# How to delete lines before and after matching pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, emc, multipath

i have a file like below. I want to search pattern ABC_DATA as a variable and after match, i want to delete from first previous "multipath" line to the line including "}" character. "}" could be after or in the same line with ABC_DATA.

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
multipaths {
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353944
alias ABC_DATA_11
}
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353945
alias DEF_DATA_11
}
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353946
alias ABC_DATA_12 }

multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353943
alias DEF_DATA_10
}
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
multipaths {
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353945
alias DEF_DATA_11
}
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353943
alias DEF_DATA_10
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='multipath\\s*{[^}]*ABC_DATA[^}]*}\\s*(\n|$)' -v ORS= '1' file
multipaths {
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353945
alias DEF_DATA_11
}
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353943
alias DEF_DATA_10
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit? What is setting `ORS='1'` doing?

Comment: Thanks Ed, it works :). i will pass ABC_DATA as first argument of bash script. So, awk -v RS='multipath\\s*{[^}]*'$1'[^}]*}\\s*(\n|$)' -v ORS= '1' /etc/multipath.test is final solution for me.

Comment: @Ed Moton. +1. Great regexp:  --> remove all unwanted data and `awk` show the  `expected output`!

Comment: @dawg I'm not setting ORS to 1, I'm setting ORS to null so awk doesn't add a newline when outputting each record, and then the `1` at the end is just the usual shorthand for `{print}`.

Comment: @solmyr make that `RS='multipath\\s*{[^}]*'"$1"'[^}]*}\\s*(\n|$)'` so that `$1` is quoted `"$1"` to avoid globbing, filename expansion, etc. when it's referenced there.

Comment: @EdMorton: Head smack. Of course. I was so fixated on `ORS='1'` that I did not notice the space! It is `ORS= '1'` (note space) so that `'1'` is the program...

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, you can use this `perl`:

```
$ perl -0777 -lpe 's/\bmultipath\h+\{[^{}]*ABC_DATA[^{}]*}\s*//g' file
multipaths {
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353945
alias DEF_DATA_11
}
multipath {
wwid 360000970000267600432533030353943
alias DEF_DATA_10
}
}
```

Comment: Should you use `-lpe`, so you don't need `print` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using sed, not really readable but definitely possible:

```
sed '
   /^multipath {/ {
     :l
     /alias ABC_DATA/ {
       :f
       /}/ d
       N
       b f
     }
     /}/ b
     N
     b l
  }' input
```

or as a single line:

```
sed '/^multipath {/{:l; /alias ABC_DATA/{:f /}/d;N;bf};/}/b;N;bl};' input
```

Answer (score 0):

ed(1) works too, if you have the global search strings on different lines than the start+end lines of the area which you want to delete:

```
echo $'g/ABC_DATA/?multipath?,/[\s\S]*}/s/.*//g\n ,n\n w\n q' | ed -s file
#or
echo $'g/ABC_DATA/?multipath?,/[\s\S]*}/d\n ,n\n w\n q' | ed -s file
```

- `echo` command supplies the ed commands, `\n` are just newlines
- same could be achieve with heredocs or ed script files, but that doesnt work for oneliners

whats actually happening there:

- search for ABC_DATA
- from there get the starting line by searching for `multipath` upwards
- get the ending line by searching downwards for any char (`[\s\S]*`) and ending with `}`
- and either "sed" it via `s` or delete via `d`
- `,n` is just for printing all output to shell and can be ommitted
- `w` saves and `q` exits - use `Q` instead of both if you are still experimenting and dont want to save changes immediately back to the file

however this will fail for this example due to the line containing `alias ABC_DATA_12 }` as both `ABC_DATA` and `}` are on the same line - i still can see merit for using ed(1) and thus wanted to share this approach.